# 'Fixing' the right click menu in gvim in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gvim, context-menu

I have installed `gvim` in `Ubuntu 12.04` and it has no right click menu.
For example, if I select a block of text and right click in the region, the size
of the selection changes up to the cursor position. I've been trying to create
a `.vimrc` by copying the relevant(at least what I can understand) parts from
the `Windows`one so I may have missed a couple of settings related to it(I think).
**How do you make the menu appear?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**description:**

```
:help popup-menu
```

**setting:**

```
:set mousemodel=popup
```

worked for me

Comment: Urggh!! Can't believe it was a `Vim` setting causing it. I thought it was just one of `Ubuntu`'s bugs. Thanks...